# Is there an open, perhaps crowd-sourced dataset of visual (image or video) data of failed and succesful prints?

Tags: camera, machine-learning, computer-vision, spaghetti-detector, artificial-intelligence

In addition to this question: [Is there a open-source pretrained TensorFlow Lite model for failed print and spaghetti detection?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/22851/36802) And in preparation of training a lightweight (TensorFlow Lite) model myself, perhaps labeling things with [Meta's Segment Anything (SAM)](https://segment-anything.com/demo). Is there an open, perhaps crowd-sourced dataset of visual (image or video) data of failed and succesful prints?

Similar to, for example [Mozilla Common Voice](https://commonvoice.mozilla.org/en/datasets) for voice recognition datasets,  [Common Crawl](https://commoncrawl.org/) for natural language processing (NLP), and [Open Images](https://storage.googleapis.com/openimages/web/index.html) for computer vision (CV).

I would like to contribute to this dataset as well as use it for training an open source model that can run on efficient TPU's like [Coral AI](https://coral.ai/products/accelerator/) for Raspberry Pi, for the purpose of Spaghetti detection, empty bed detection and perhaps for other print defects.